# Count number of all calls to a class function

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class like this:

```cpp
class Handler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Handler(Scene *scene, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Handler();
    void runTests(const QVector<Test> *tests);

private:
    Scene *m_scene; // parent, not owned
    const QVector<Test> *m_tests; // Not owned, set by others
};
```

The function `runTests` is:

```cpp
void Handler::runTests(const QVector<Test> *tests)
{
    if (tests->isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    m_tests = tests;

    // ... do things ...

    return;
}
```

I intend to count the number of calls to `runTests` function by any object instantiated from `Handler` class. I'm confused how to use `static` members to do so. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it shouldn't matter what `Handler` calls it, then `static` is the way to go.
You can place the `static` member in the class, as a private variable, or just put it inside the function.

```
void Handler::runTests(const QVector<Test> *tests)
{
    static size_t _numTimesCalled = 0;
    ++_numTimesCalled;

    if (tests->isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    m_tests = tests;

    // ... do things ...

    return;
}
```

Comment: If it's static inside the runTests then how do you access the count in the end? Also what if some class overrides runTests() without calling the parent runTests()? Better make that method final.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, to your first point: that's why I mentioned putting it in the class instead of the function. Context of the question matters in this case, but I'm presuming its being used in the function itself. It seems to have worked for Op, so I'll assume that's what they were doing. To your second point, I partially agree. Overridden functions which don't call the parent would definitely affect the result, but that might be okay in the case of Op's usage.